# How to increment a value in a text file and generate corresponding incremented ouput text files?

Tags: bash, text, awk, increment

I have these type of bash text files :

```
#!/bin/sh 

#SBATCH --partition=mono-shared
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --time=05:00:00

#SBATCH --mail-user=
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --clusters=

module load rdkit

srun /opt/xxx /home/rand/data/DB_split/DB_0001.txt 0.001 /models/computetd/ /home/rand/DBIS_results/DB_0001
```

I have 455 input text files. I want to generate 455 correponding bash files. Each bash files should have the bold numerics incremented "srun /opt/xxx /home/rand/data/DB_split/DB_**0001**.txt 0.001 /models/computetd/ /home/rand/DBIS_results/DB_**0001**" and should be named Bash0001.txt, Bash002.txt etc accordingly.

Not sure if I am clear.
Is this possible which tool should I use?
Is awk an option? I looked at the tool but couldn't figure the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have above file named as `Bash0001.txt`, you can use this script:

```
for ((i=2; i<=455; i++)); do
   printf -v fn '%04d' $i
   sed "s/DB_0001/DB_${fn}/g" Bash0001.txt > "Bash${fn}.txt" 
done
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank a lot :) In my case I had to change print to printf.

Comment: Yes `print` instead of `printf` was a typo. Glad it worked out.